# Display values outside of the piechart

Tags: swift, charts, pie-chart

I am having trouble displaying the values outside of my piechart.  Currently the values overlap, is there anyway to improve this?  Please see image below.

```
chartDataSet.valueLinePart1Length = 0.5
chartDataSet.valueLinePart2Length = 1
//set.xValuePosition = .outsideSlice
chartDataSet.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupPiChart() {
    // This will align label text to top right corner
    let l = pieChartView.legend
    l.horizontalAlignment = .left
    l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
    l.orientation = .horizontal
    l.xEntrySpace = 10
    l.yEntrySpace = 0
    l.font = self.isPhone ? Typography.robotoRegular14 : Typography.robotoRegular18

    self.pieChartView.entryLabelFont = Typography.robotoRegular14
    self.pieChartView.drawHoleEnabled = false
    self.pieChartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
    self.pieChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```